# Facebook. Linking to user profile?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, profile

I need to create link to the users profile in my facebook page. When I hover over the "Home" button it shows the following link http:/www.facebook.com/?ref=tn_tnmn , in all my accounts. So can I use this to provide a hyperlink? Say

```
<a href="http:/www.facebook.com/?ref=tn_tnmn" > Go to your profile </a>
```

Comment: The Home button goes to the News Feed, not the user's profile/timeline.  Which do you want?

Comment: i want to go to the user's profile.

Comment: Then get the URL for the user's profile based on their uid (e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/4?fields=link  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution would be to use this URL format :
`https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=FACEBOOK_USER_ID`

Answer (score 3):

Earlier solution by Lix won't work

User following format:
https://www.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID

Upvote if works !!!