# How to get facebook user id from scoped user id to open profile page on fb app?

Tags: facebook, profile, uid

Is there a way to open a user profile page on the FB app with the scoped user id? If not how to get the real id from the scoped one?

Comment: Ask for the link property on the user object

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to use this URL format :

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=FACEBOOK_USER_ID

as they answer in :
[Facebook. Linking to user profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507833/facebook-linking-to-user-profile)

Comment: This is to open it in a browser, I want to open it in the mobile app.

Comment: Read Facebook documents, it's the same link just different syntax